# using 3d packages for android icon design

Tags: android

if this is a silly question, am sorry about that. I was wondering if its possible to design android icons using a 3d modelling package like blender? i know i have to stick to the guidelines documented already, but was just wondering if anyone had come across or done something similar? Its that little part of the icons(launchers) being able to have a slight perspective  and looking through the requirements to design icons it seems i might be a lot faster using a 3d modelling package and then following part of the icons template guide(based from my requirement though!).  what you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your 3D setup in Blender.  Render a frame.  Save the frame, size it down and try it.

Answer (score 0):

not really a programming questions, but I guess whatever software you are the most proficient with would be the best choice.

Comment: oops.. sorry, i forgot where i was and did not realise where i was posting.